# Regular expression to extract a word between last 2 occurrence of colons

Tags: regex

I am new to reg-ex.
I would like to have regular expression to extract a word between last 2 occurrence of colons.

Example : input

```
lst:idm:am::000000023:user:device:FFFFFFFF
```

output :  device

Similarly I would like to have one more expression to extract "user" from above input.

I have tried as `/\:.*\:/g`.  I am getting the result as `:idm:am::000000023:user:device:`.

Thanks.

Comment: Split with `:` and get the items you need using indexing.

Comment: This is kind of input to generic configuration file.   I can provide only reg-x.  So I cannot use any code.  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:([^:]+):[^:]*$` works with group 1 as output.

`[^:]` means "match any character that is not `:`"

`$` is end of line

Giving you "find end of line, match any previous junk until a colon, capture everything unitl the previous colon"

An easier approach would be `let x = text.split( ':' ); let match = x[ x.length - 2 ];`

Comment: :([^:]+):[^:]*$  is perfect .  Thanks